# All of my work disapeared after running the file. Error: File ended while scanning use of \textbf

Tags: errors

I have a serious problem with my latex file. I was working on my article, when suddenly **all the work I made disappeared** after running the document. I have to submit the article in one week. In the error line, only one error appeared:

**File ended while scanning use of \textbf**, but it didn't show in which line the problem is located.

Does someone know what to do and where can I find my work?

Thank you.

Comment: Do please tell us more about your computing setup. E.g., which operating system, which TeX distribution, and which editor do you employ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeX never edits or changes your source file in any way, so any changes in your source (and any backups) are a feature of your editor (that you have not named).

The error means you have a missing `}`.

You should be able to detect the error from the log. There is no line number as the error is detected as the file ended, but for example

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
000

\clearpage

111
\clearpage

aaa

\textbf{bbb

ccc

\end{document}
```

Produces

```
] [2])
Runaway argument?
{bbb \par ccc \par \end {document} 
! File ended while scanning use of \textbf .
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> dd937
         
?
```

so here the `[2]` tells you it had just shipped out page 2 and then an argument starting `bbb` was never closed. From which you should be able to find
`\textbf{bbb` fairly easily.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!